# Netbeans plugin for Sass and Compass

Tags: windows, netbeans, sass, compass-sass, netbeans-plugins

Is there a plugin for Netbeans in Windows that supports both Sass and Compass?

Answer (score 1):

Native support for SASS [has recently](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeanswebclient/entry/editing_css_preprocessors_sources) been added to the Netbeans codebase - until the next major version is released, you can get it using the current "[development version](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/)".

For compilation support, you still need to install ruby, sass and compass separately, and point netbeans to its path (Options -> Miscellaneous -> CSS Preprocessors).